# How to support both kinds of URLs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'd like to be able to call GET by both:

**/api/Test/Test/1**

**/api/Test/Test?id=1**

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Test(int id)
    {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

How to configure the route?

I have the default:

```
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

This makes "/api/Test/Test?id=1" work but not "/api/Test/Test/1"

I tried to add the attribute routing on the action, which makes "/api/Test/Test/1" work but now "/api/Test/Test?id=1" doesn't work:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/test/test/{id}")]
        public string Test(string id)
        {
            return "a";
        }
```

Comment: What is the .NET version you are using?

Comment: I am on ASP.NET, not Core

Comment: OK, so I created a new ASP.NET MVC project and I can't reproduce what you're describing, although there are some differences that I can spot, for example the route is similar but not exactly the same. With the default route config, a method like the ones you're describing above work in both situations. Could you provide some more details about your environment? A git repo with a minimal working example of your problem would really help.

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis That's probably because you just ran without any other modifications. Here are the exact steps: 1. Create a new app and select "Web API" template. 2. In `ValuesController`, rename the `Get` action to `Test` and add the `[HttpGet]` attribute to it. 
Calling "api/Values/Test?id=5" works, but not "api/Values/Test/5"

Comment: This is very interesting. When creating a default MVC project, what you want works out of the box, but on the API project template it doesn't! Even though the route configs are seemingly identical. I am investigating this with a friend, I'll get back to you as soon as I figure anything out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with the ASP.NET Web API template, I configured the WebApi routes like this:

```cs
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

You will need to be careful with the actions you include in your controller. For example, I have the `ValuesController` like this:

```cs
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Test(string id = "")
    {
        return "test " + id;
    }
}
```

With the routes configured as shown above, the api will respond to the following requests:

```
/api/values/2
/api/values/test/2
/api/values/test?id=2
```

However, things get complicated if you add a second `HttpGet` action in the same controller. The server, when trying to respond to the request that maps to the first route (`DefaultApi`), won't be able to figure out which get action to send. The `DefaultApi` route kind of relies on a convention that a controller will only have 1 action to service each kind of HTTP request. If you add a second `HttpGet` action named `Try`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public string Try(int id)
{
    return "try " + id;
}
```

The server will respond as follows:

```
/api/values/test/2    -> WORKS
/api/values/test?id=2 -> WORKS
/api/values/try/2     -> WORKS
/api/values/try?id=2  -> WORKS
/api/values/2         -> DOES NOT WORK, Multiple GET methods. server can't decide which to use
```

If you intend to use more than 1 method for each type of HTTP request in the same controller, I recommend removing the `DefaultApi` route and keeping only the `ActionApi`. Another example:

```cs
// Removed "DefaultApi"
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

```cs
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Test(int id)
    {
        return "test " + id;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Try(int id)
    {
        return "try " + id;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Play(string str)
    {
        return "play " + str;
    }
}
```

Now, the server will handle the following requests successfully:

```
/api/values/test/3       -> WORKS
/api/values/test?id=3    -> WORKS
/api/values/try/3        -> WORKS
/api/values/try?id=3     -> WORKS
/api/values/play?str=3   -> WORKS
```

However, these will not work:

```
/api/values/play/3       -> DOES NOT WORK
/api/values/play?id=3    -> DOES NOT WORK
```

Parameter isn't called "id" for the method "Play", the server doesn't know what you want. Response:

```xml
<Error>
    <Message>
        No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44327/api/values/play/3'.
    </Message>
    <MessageDetail>
        No action was found on the controller 'Values' that matches the request.
    </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

```
/api/values/3
```

The server expects what comes after the controller name, `values` in  this case, to be a controller action. The `3` obviously isn't so the server doesn't know how to handle the request.

```xml
<Error>
    <Message>
        No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44327/api/values/3'.
    </Message>
    <MessageDetail>
        No action was found on the controller 'Values' that matches the name '3'.
    </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

I hope this post gives you enough information to configure your API however you want.

Comment: So I was missing {action} ‍♂️ when defining the route... Oh boy. Thank you!

Comment: You should write a question with the appropriate tags and specify exactly how you want your routing to work. Help us help you.