# Unable to disambiguate controller actions based on required query parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core 6 routing is unable to disambiguate between two controller actions with the same verb and route, but different required parameters. This used to work in ASP.NET Framework.

Here's a simple example using ASP.NET Core 6:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace slim
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            builder.Services.AddControllers();

            var app = builder.Build();
            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }

    [ApiController]
    public class SomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/somepath")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Add([FromBody] SomeModel item) => Ok();

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/somepath")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddMany(int count) => Ok();
    }

    public class SomeModel
    {
        public string? SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It throws an AmbigiousMatchException when I try to make any of the following calls using PowerShell:

```
Invoke-RestMethod "http://localhost:5186/somepath" -Method POST -Body @{ SomeProperty="value" }
Invoke-RestMethod "http://localhost:5186/somepath" -Method POST
Invoke-RestMethod "http://localhost:5186/somepath?count=4" -Method POST
```

Anyone know why was this removed in ASP.NET Core? Is there an easy way to get it working again?

**UPDATE**: I settled on a solution very similar to the one suggested in the accepted answer. Here are the details:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Ensures that routing will only consider this action a candidate for a particular request if all required parameters that
    /// CAN accept data from the query are present in either the route data or the query string. NOTE: This was actually the
    /// default behavior in WebAPI, but it is no longer enforced in ASP.NET Core, so two action overloads that differ only by
    /// their required parameters are now considered routing collisions (unless you apply this attribute to one of them).
    /// </summary>
    public class RequireQueryParametersAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValidForRequest(RouteContext routeContext, ActionDescriptor action)
        {
            foreach (var p in action.Parameters.OfType<ControllerParameterDescriptor>())
            {
                // Only check action method parameters that are REQUIRED
                if (!p.ParameterInfo.IsOptional)
                {
                    // Only check action method parameters that allow binding to QUERY parameters
                    if (p.BindingInfo?.BindingSource == null || p.BindingInfo.BindingSource.CanAcceptDataFrom(BindingSource.Query))
                    {
                        // Only check action method parameters that are NOT present in the route data
                        if (!routeContext.RouteData.DataTokens.ContainsKey(p.Name))
                        {
                            // Action method says the parameter MUST be present, at it is so this action is NOT valid for this request
                            // if the query parameter is missing
                            if (!routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.ContainsKey(p.Name))
                                return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I found this [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59268581/how-to-configure-routing-in-asp-net-core-3-0-to-use-overload-httpget-method-wi), which suggests the only solution is to convert query parameters to path segments so routing will consider them. However, this would be a breaking change to the API, and would also be awful with multiple query parameters (which order must the be specified in the path? should it matter? do I need to support all permutations?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you'd not use overloaded methods on controllers with the same path and verb.  This is no longer supported in Core.

But, if breaking changes are a no-no, you could add an Action Constraint that will be evaluated by the routing framework.

```
public class RequiresQueryAttribute : Attribute, IActionConstraint
{
    private readonly string _valueName;

    public RequiresQueryAttribute(string valueName)
    {
        _valueName = valueName;
    }

    public int Order => 0;

    public bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext context)
    {
        return context.RouteContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.ContainsKey(_valueName);
    }
}
```

Then use this attribute on the item that accepts a query parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/somepath")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Add([FromBody] SomeModel item) => Ok();

[HttpPost]
[Route("/somepath")]
[RequiresQuery("count")]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddMany(int count) => Ok();
```

The routing framework will evaluate the Attribute "RequiresQuery" as it derives from IActionConstraint and ensure that Accept returns true before assuming that the route matches.

You could get best of both worlds and mark original as obsolete and send a warning back in the response, whilst also creating a new method with a new route:

```
[Obsolete("Use /somepath/many instead.")]
[HttpPost]
[Route("/somepath")]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddManyDeprecated(int count)
{
    Response.Headers.Add("Warning", "199 - Deprecated: Use /somepath/many instead.");
    return Ok();
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("/somepath/many")]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddMany(int count) => Ok();
```

Comment: Thanks -- after more investigation I settled on a very similar solution. Updated the question with the details.